# How closely do the hyper-surface areas of unit spheres of dimension > 7 approach 4π?

Tags: area, spheres

I read [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hypersphere.html) that "for the unit hypersphere, the hyper-surface area reaches a maximum and then decreases towards 0 as *n* increases...As a result, the seven-dimensional unit hypersphere has maximum hyper-surface area (Le Lionnais 1983; Wells 1986, p. 60)."

How closely do the hyper-surface areas of unit spheres of dimension > 7 approach 4π?
From the chart I saw, it looks like dimension 13 may be the closest.

Comment: What chart did you see?

Comment: The chart, x-axis indicating dimension and y-axis indicating hyper-surface area of unit hypersphere, here: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/images/eps-gif/HypersphereArea_900.gif

Comment: The formula for the "area" is given.  Why not just substitute for $n$?